# Multiple points on same routes with Google-yandex Maps navigation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, yandex-maps

In my html app user want to navigate google or yandex navigation for a point

```
//geoURL='geo:'+originLat+','+originLot+'q='+DestinationLat+','+DestinationLong;
            var geoURL='maps://?q='+DestinationLat+','+DestinationLong;
             window.open(geoURL,'_blank');
```

I do this with that code.So when user click any product to navigate my app navigate to google or yandex navigation and it start navigation...But how can Use that for multiple points?For example my user firstly want to go point A,then point B and finally point C...How can I open google or yandex maps navigation with this 3 point?

Comment: Google Maps URLs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action.

Comment: Thanks @xomena but apple not support this.So I must use geo:...How can I use that with geo attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Yandex.Navigator has a public URL-schema for app opening. Here is [the documentation](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/navigator/doc/concepts/navigator-url-params-docpage/?from=SO#route-via) (it's in Russian).

Link will be as follows:

```
yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_from=55.75&lon_from=37.58&lat_to=55.75&lon_to=37.64&lat_via_0=55.75&lon_via_0=37.62
```

`lat_via_0` and `lon_via_0` are for coordinates of the 1st route point after route start (point B in your terms).

If you need Yandex.Maps app to be opened than you should use `yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/` links. [More about it here](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/About-docpage/?from=SO).